# Error in capifony after installation

Tags: ruby, symfony, centos, capistrano, capifony

I am trying to use capifony deployment tool for deploying Symfony2 based project. Everything worked fine on Ubuntu 14.04. My staging server is CentOS and this is the error that I am seeing there:

[user@apache2 Symfony]$ cap -vT
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/inifile-3.0.0/lib/inifile.rb:558: undefined (?...) sequence: /\A"(.*)(?<!\\)"\z/ (SyntaxError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capifony-2.8.1/lib/capifony_symfony2.rb:6
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
    from Capfile:3:in`load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:180:in `load_from_file'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in`load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in`each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in`load_recipes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in`load_recipes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in`execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/bin/cap:4
    from /usr/bin/cap:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/cap:19

What should I do? Please note that I do not know much about Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall inifile 3.0.0 and install 2.0.2

(Note: now the dependecy is to the **2.0.2** version)

```
gem uninstall inifile
gem install inifile -v 2.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've deinstalled inifile 3.0.0 and installed inifile 2.0.0 and after that this error is gone.